# Using PhoneGap to make purchases of products from my in app catalogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have a catalogue of products on my PhoneGap app, and wanted to know if it's possible to take payments from people within the app, and not directing them to a safari browser web view? i.e. having the user enter their bank details et etc..

I have looked into In-App Purchases and I dont believe this is what I need. It will hopefully be something like a payment gateway on a website, but just build to integrate into PhoneGap? Wishful thinking maybe.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a paypal plugin for phonegap and it is working great: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/PayPalPlugin.

Contact me if you need help with a plugin integration. This version is working with phonegap/cordova 2.0.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a version for the iOS also?

Comment: Got it sorry, my bad :) https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PayPalPlugin

Comment: Yes there is and it has a better support then plugin version for android. I have created my app 6 months ago, at that point I had to rewrite part of the code so it can be executed on newer phonegap versions. Last version works like charm.

Comment: FYI to all that stumble on this from Google, the iOS version of this plugin has moved [here](http://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin)